# How to find the lowest and highest date based on certain value in another column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel table like this which contains Name and Date as shown below. I want to find out the lowest and highest date based on Name on right side.The right table already contains the Name. I want to get their lowest and highest date based on Name

[image]

The final result should be like this

[image]

What should be the formula to get this result ?

Comment: You can use either a pivot table or `minifs` https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/minifs-function-6ca1ddaa-079b-4e74-80cc-72eef32e6599 / `maxifs` https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883

Comment: pivot table : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cell `E2`, copied right to `F2` and all copied down :

```
=AGGREGATE(15-(COLUMN(A1)=2),6,$B$2:$B$9/($A$2:$A$9=$D2),1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Cell **E2** = `=MINIFS($B$2:$B$9,$A$2:$A$9,D2)`

Cell **F2** = `=MAXIFS($B$2:$B$9,$A$2:$A$9,D2)`

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer but my excel does not support MINIFS and MAXIFS.. it has MIN, MAX and IF though.. could you please rewrite the formula using MIN, MAX and IF commands?